# IE7 CSS issue with overlapping divs

Tags: css, layout, internet-explorer-7

I have this page: http://jsfiddle.net/aJNAw/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.wrapper
{
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.page_header_billboard
{
    background: #669933;
    height: 376px;
    width:960px;
}
.homebox
{
    float:right;
    clear:right;
    position:relative;
    right:20px;
    top:36px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.homebox a
{
    background:#ccc;
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    opacity:0.6;
    filter:Alpha(opacity=60);
}

.homebox a:hover
{
    opacity:0.8;
    filter:Alpha(opacity=80);
}

.homebox a span
{
    display:inline-block;
    color:#333;
    line-height:27px;
}

.homebox_middle
{
    margin:1px 0;
}



</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="homebox">
        <a href="#" class="homebox_first"></a>
        <a href="#" class="homebox_middle"></a>
        <a href="#" class="homebox_last"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="page_header_billboard"></div>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

and the layout doesn't work in IE7 but it's fine in other browsers (chrome, firefox).

Would anyone be able to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `<div class="homebox">` inside `<div class="page_header_billboard">`.

[***Live Demo***](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Hzwd2/show/light/) ([edit](http://jsfiddle.net/Hzwd2/))

Comment: Sigh, yeah, not sure why I didn't catch that.  Makes the whole negative margin unnecessary.

Comment: @D.N.: At least you did come up with something that also worked, even if it wasn't the easiest way :)

Comment: @greener: you can also completely leave out `display: inline-block` and have the same effect.  @thirtydot: I've gotten really good at "kicking and beating" CSS into working, but sometimes I get so lost in the minutiae that the easiest way isn't so apparent.

Answer (score 2):

Add `display: inline` to your floats (children of `.wrapper`). Force layout on the container via applying `zoom: 1` to `.wrapper`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an IE7 to test on, but your problem is likely the use of `display: inline-block`  IE7 has some display problems using `inline-block`.  This might help you:

http://grasshopperpebbles.com/css/css-inline-block-ie7-hack/

Comment: It's probably not the best thing, but it has no effect on this test case.  Leaving it in or removing it (the latter being preferred) render exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Put the page_header_billboard at the top, and set the margin-top of homebox to -376px (the height of the page_header_billboard).

This works in IE6, IE7, and FF3.6.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.wrapper
{
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.page_header_billboard
{
    background: #669933;
    height: 376px;
    width:960px;
}
.homebox
{
    margin-top: -376px;
    float:right;
    clear:right;
    position:relative;
    right:20px;
    top:36px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.homebox a
{
    background:#ccc;
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    opacity:0.6;
    filter:Alpha(opacity=60);
}

.homebox a:hover
{
    opacity:0.8;
    filter:Alpha(opacity=80);
}

.homebox a span
{
    color:#333;
    line-height:27px;
}

.homebox_middle
{
    margin:1px 0;
}



</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="page_header_billboard"></div>
    <div class="homebox">
        <a href="#" class="homebox_first"></a>
        <a href="#" class="homebox_middle"></a>
        <a href="#" class="homebox_last"></a>
    </div>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```